# Excel activex combo box disappear

Tags: excel, combobox, activex

working in excel 2010 sheet & i have a few combo box's around 20 & i right click on of them then suddenly all of them are disappeared but there VBA code and properties still exist so please can some one help me.

the visible is set to fulse

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem in the properties of the combobox, height and lift of properties size i just adjust them and they appear again.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else made the mistake I did. My issue was that I didn't have my object properties set to "don't move or size with cells". I thought my objects disappeared, but they were actually just "pushed" out of view as I was filtering and un-filtering data.

It took a moment for me to figure out since there is no "pan to object" feature within the selection pane.